# How to pass list of indices along a dimension of a 2D array in numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have a 2D numpy array of shape, say, 4x3:

```py
myarray = np.array([[0,1,2],
                    [3,4,5],
                    [6,7,8],
                    [9,10,11]])
```

and I have a list of indices corresponding to the second dimension, with length 4 and values ranging from 0 to 2, i.e., for each of the 4 rows, I have one different index corresponding to the value I want to select from that row:

```py
idx = [0,2,1,2]
```

How can I pass this list of indices to the 2D array and get as a result the following 1D array of length 4, where each element corresponds to the indexed value from each row of the original array?

```py
array([ 0,  5,  7, 11])
```

I am looking for a solution that doesn't require looping as I intend to do this for very large arrays.

Comment: Hey paulo, I have added an answer but feel guilty about not asking you what all have you tried yet? and what part of it didn't work? The community goal is to improve understanding and help, not just provide answers.

Comment: Please add a [mre]. If *arr2D* is your 2D array and *idx* is your index list `arr2D.T[idx, np.arange(len(idx))]`. You don't need any loop.

Comment: Hey Devesh, I did try a few things using numpy.apply_along_axis and for loops, but I was wondering if there was something faster and more obvious that I couldn't figure out. Michael's reply did exactly what I needed in just one line, so I'll answer my question later with his suggestion. Thank you both for helping me out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use zip to iterate over two arrays simultaneously.

```
data = [
    [1,2,3,4,5],
    [2,4,6,8,10],
    [3,6,9,12,15]
]

indexes = [0,1,2]

for (arr, i) in zip(data, indexes):
    print(arr[i])
    
# Or more pythonic way     
print([arr[i] for (arr,i) in zip(data, indexes)]) # [1, 4, 9]
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this without using a loop? I worry this my get too slow for very large arrays

Comment: @paulo  Short answer no. Point is that you have to go through every element in the array at least once to pick the desired value, and you can't skip the loop in that process. Somewhere you might find a Jazzy syntax but it must be looping internally, That's inevitable (_insert loop saying *you shall not pass*_) .

Comment: ah ok. I was trying to run away from looping as much as I could. But still, for what I want to do your answer might be the most efficient solution. Thanks!

Comment: @paulo, Request you please accept the answer, It doesn't only help me get a few rep points but also tells us that you got the answer you were looking for.

Answer (score 2):

For simplicity I will reduce the dimensions to 2x2 to make the example easier to show.

Suppose we have a 2D array:

```
arr = np.array(
  [[1,2], 
   [3,4]]
)
nrows = arr.shape[0] # 1000 in your case
```

and a 1D array of indexes:

```
idx = np.array([1,0])
```

In your case the 2D array will have dims 1000x40 and the 1D array of indexes dim 1000.

1. Convert indexes into a 2D array of shape 1000x1

```
idx = np.array([0,1]).reshape(-1,1)
```

2. Use the following to select element at index in each row according to the 1D vector idx

```
arr[np.arange(arr.shape[0])[:,None], idx]
```

The  `np.arange(arr.shape[0])[:,None]` simply generates a selector for all rows in your 2D array.

Your output will look like this.

```
array([[2],
       [3]])
```

Hope this is helpful!